# Use Laravel template in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a template in Laravel that uses Blade. I would like to share that template with WordPress. Is it possible? I want to do it because I have a lot of if/then logic in the templates and I don't want to maintain two versions of the template if I don't have to.

Here is a overly simplified example:

**site.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>        
    <body>
    @include('layouts.site.header')
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

**site.header.blade.php**

```
<header>
    <img src="{{$imageUrl}}">
</header>
```

Any way to use the **site.blade.php** template in WordPress? Or if not, is there a way to get the HTML output from **site.header.blade.php** into WordPress efficiently?

Comment: Not sure about your requirements but there is a WordPress plugin to use `Blade` in `WordPress`, [check it here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/blade/installation/).

Comment: That plugin doesn't support the syntax of latest version of blade unfortunately.

Comment: I realize this is a couple years old, but this supports Laravel 5.x at the moment: https://github.com/ekandreas/bladerunner

Comment: Hi Justin, maybe I am too late, however I have just developed Wordpress theme framework that is based on Laravel Blade - https://github.com/anrw/classy